# UPS Voltage fluctuation from 240 to 220 Volt

Tags: ups

Dear readers from this forum.
I live in North East Thailand. I do have 4 UPS units from "Etech EGO" (1000 VA 500 Watt). I have 3 phase electricity which wil give me 240 to 250 Volt on different phases. Therefore I use an AVR for some equipment in the living room and connect on that group from the AVR the UPS units. Everything works as it should, but if I connect a UPS in another room without a stabilizer than I will see 235 to 240 Volt on the display and it will drop from time to time to around the 220 Volt also if I connect a separate meter it gives the same value.
I do not like the fact that it fluctuate that much, which is in my opinion not good for the connected equipment. I have my thoughts about the UPS units.
Could you please advice?
Mr. Dutchie

Answer (score 1):

The UPSes are not (expensive) double-conversion units but (cheap) failover models.

This means, that as long as the mains input is inside specs (and 220-240 is), the consumers will supplied directly from the mains input, but only when input goes out of acceptable range will the inverter start up and take the load.

That said: Voltage fluctuations between 220 and 240 Volts are very unlikely to harm any equipment plugged in. The only equipment using the mains without any power conversion are heaters and some types of motor, none of which are expected to suffer from diminishing reliability from those fluctuations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer. I have to admit that by power outage the UPS perfect 220 Volt displays which is great, but when connected to main outlet without a stabilizer I've got these problems from Voltage fluctuations. I did assume that when a UPS plugged in, should have a clean 220 Volt output, because UPSes are doing 2 things, stabilize the current and backup by power failure, unfortunately they are not able to stabilize. That's where the AVS comes in, right?

Comment: This depends on the type of UPS used: A "double conversion" UPS will rectify and deripple the input AC into something resembling smooth DC, then create new AC from it. This is expensive and not very efficient, but it not only creates and **u**interruptable **p**ower **s**upply but also smoothes out a wobbly mains. The "failover" type will use a fast (mechanical or electronic) switch to provide power from the inverter only if the mains fails. While this is very efficient, it will connect the equipment directly to mains most of the time

Comment: Well, thank you very much for the information. I've got 4 UPS units from the same brand. I have to find out which UPS brand has the specifications you gave as requirements and how expensive they might be. May I ask if I could use an AVR and after connect a UPS unit to the AVR? Because that's what I did in 2 rooms already and that works fine. After all it will be much cheaper for me to do it that way for just one room.